# How to deal with a large proportion of missing values

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, missing-data

I have to run a regression using a number of variables in a given dataset. However, more than 45% of the values are missing(NA).

I am not even sure if they are missing at random, but I presume they are not(since for variables such as age, sex or religion the proportion of NA values is much lower than for variables such as political identification).

In this case, should I use models such as kNN for imputing the missing values? Or is there any take on how to deal with (probably)non-random large proportions of NAs?